# Can more recent evidence be considered in an appeal?

Tags: evidence, civil-procedure, pro-se

I requested an impartial special education hearing to establish eligibility under IDEA for my son.  I lost at hearing but won on review.  (I am in a "two tier" state, New York.)  The evidence considered in the hearing, and the review, was all collected prior to the start of the current school year.

The school district has recently filed an appeal to state court (county supreme court).  The petition mentions some education records that were generated in the current school year (i.e. based on the student's current school year academic performance).  Will those recent records be admissible in the district's appeal?